# Como puedo actualizar mis datos al regresar a la pantalla anterior en react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

En esta primera pantalla del Home mando los datos a la pantalla del Detalle:
En esta pantalla quiero que se actualizen los datos que edito en la pantalla del Detalle y se refresque también en esta pantalla, por favor si alguien puede darme su ayuda la acepto con todo gusto, gracias!

```
       export interface Props {    
list: any;
route: { params: any };
navigation: { openDrawer: () => void; navigate: (route:string) => void };


}
  export interface State {
    Posts: Post[],
    isLoading: boolean
  }
  class Home extends React.Component<Props, State> {

constructor(props: Props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
    Posts: [], 
    isLoading: true,
  };
}

async componentDidMount() {      
  const muroService = new MuroService();
  var response = await muroService.ObtenerPublicaciones();
  
  if(this.props.route.params.Post){
    const Post = this.state.Posts.findIndex(element => element.PostId == this.props.route.params.Post.PostId )
    let newPost = [...this.state.Posts];
    newPost[Post] = {...newPost[Post]};
    this.setState({
      Posts: newPost
    });
  }

  this.setState({ Posts: response.Posts, isLoading: false });
}

render() {
  if(this.state.isLoading){
    return (
      <Container style={styles.container}>
        <Header>
          <Left>
            <Button transparent>
              <Icon
                active
                name="menu"
                onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.openDrawer() }}
              />
            </Button>
          </Left>
          <Body>
            <Title>LOBBY 1.0</Title>
          </Body>
          <Right />
        </Header>
          <View style={[styles.content, styles.horizontal]}>
            <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#0000ff"/>       
          </View>
      </Container>
    )
  } 
  else{
  return (
    <Container style={styles.container}>
      <Header>
        <Left>
          <Button transparent>
            <Icon
              active
              name="menu"
              onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.openDrawer() }}
            />
          </Button>
        </Left>
        <Body>
          <Title>LOBBY 1.0</Title>
        </Body>
        <Right />
      </Header>
      <Content>
      {
        this.state.Posts.map((post: Post, index:number) => (
          <PostComponent navigation={this.props.navigation} Post={ post } key={ post.PostId + '' } ></PostComponent>
        ))
      }
      </Content>
    </Container>
  );
  }
}
```

Y en esta modifico los datos y los quiero mandar hacia la pantalla de Home nuevamente pero actualizados y no me deja hacerlo, intente hacerlo con setState pero lo estoy haciendo mal, alguna sugerencia que tengan? Cualquier sugerencia la acepto con todo gusto, tal vez sea algo sencillo pero ya se me hizo algo dificil

```
       goBack() {
         this.props.navigation.goBack( { Post: this.state.Post })
       }

      <Icon
        name="arrow-back"
        onPress={() => { this.goBack() } }
      />
```

Aquí estoy intentando cambiar el estado del arreglo al que acabo de actualizar en la pantalla del Detalle

```
async componentDidMount() {      
  const muroService = new MuroService();
  var response = await muroService.ObtenerPublicaciones();
  
  if(this.props.route.params.PostId){
    const Post = this.state.Posts.findIndex(element => element.PostId == this.props.route.params.PostId )
    let newPost = [...this.state.Posts];
    newPost[Post] = {...newPost[Post]};
    this.setState({
      Posts: newPost
    });
  }

  this.setState({ Posts: response.Posts, isLoading: false });
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes por favor compartir tu componente de Home en su totalidad? Y porqué haces `this.props.route.params.PostId` si a la hora de navegar a Home haces `{this.props.navigation.navigate("HomeDetalle", { Post: this.props.Post } )}`. ¿No debería de ser  `this.props.route.params.Post`?

Comment: Cierto, es que andaba haciendo pruebas pasando el Id, disculpa.

Comment: constructor(props: Props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { 
        Posts: [], 
        isLoading: true,
      };
    }

Comment: ` async componentDidMount() {      
      const muroService = new MuroService();
      var response = await muroService.ObtenerPublicaciones();
      
      if(this.props.route.params.Post){
        const Post = this.state.Posts.findIndex(element => element.PostId == this.props.route.params.Post.PostId )
        let newPost = [...this.state.Posts];
        newPost[Post] = {...newPost[Post]};
        this.setState({
          Posts: newPost
        });
      }

      this.setState({ Posts: response.Posts, isLoading: false });
    }`

Comment: Por favor no compartas segmentos de código en la sección de comentarios. `Edita` tu pregunta.

Comment: Disculpa, es mi segunda pregunta aquí, ya la edité

Comment: De componente a otro que usan los mismos datos , tienes el reactcontext , por ej: te logeas y tienes que actualizar el nombre del ususario en varios componentes

Comment: Hasta ahora no lo he solucionado... He intentado muchas cosas pero no tengo un ejemplo claro de cómo hacerlo sinceramente.

Comment: Sabes si deberia usar ComponentDidUpdate o algo asi? Para actualizar mi data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No sé, si esta es la forma correcta de hacer lo que preguntas, pero yo lo pude solucionar de esta manera, básicamente tengo una aplicación en react native con dos pantallas inicio que lista las tareas y la pantalla dos para registrar tareas, voy de la pantalla de inicio a la pantalla de registro y agrego una nueva tarea le doy guardar y vuelvo atrás y no se refresca la lista, por tanto, no aparece la que acabo de agregar, así que cierro la aplicación y vuelvo a ingresar y efectivamente aparece la nueva tarea.

Esta solución capta el evento focus, para saber en qué momento el usuario está viendo la pantalla y así solicitar que consulte si hay nuevos datos para mostrar.

```js
const [shoppingList, setShoppingList] = useState([]);
let focusListener = null;

useEffect(() => {
    createTableShoppingLists();
    focusListener = navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
        console.log('Updating because screen entered on focus .....');
        ReadShopingList();
    });
    return function cleanUp() {
        focusListener.remove();
    };
}, []);
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código (y corrige el formato): lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.